# Get specific queries in Heidi SQL Command-Statistics

Tags: mysql, heidisql

There are really meaningful to me of command-statistics in Heidi SQL. I wonder If I can get up to each query was run in Heidi not just by total each command type only. Anyone can suggest to me how I can get that? Thanks for any help

[image: Image Command Statistics from Heidi SQL]

Answer (score 0):

What HeidiSQL shows in the command statistics tab are the results of a special MySQL command:

```
SHOW /*!50002 GLOBAL */ STATUS LIKE 'Com\_%';
```

You will get something like this when you fire that query:

```
Variable_name | Value
Com_select | 249078098
Com_insert | 81310060
...
```

HeidiSQL parses these variables, calculates the average values per second/hour by dividing against the uptime seconds. MySQL (and MariaDB) don't offer more detailed query types in these variables.

In order to get the full queries somewhere, you could enable the general_log (for MySQL 5.6+):

```
SET global general_log=1;
SET global log_output='table';
```

This will start logging *all* queries to mysql.general_log.
View these logs with

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log
```

Be aware that logging all queries draws serious performance on the server, so you should not do that for a longer time on production servers.

On older MySQL servers, you can turn on file logging in your my.cnf/my.ini:

```
log = log_file_name
```

But this will get cumbersome as you have to go through the log file to analyze the queries.